# Determine height of UITableViewHeaderView dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm running into a problem setting a tableHeaderView for a UITableView. I would like to have a detailsView be set as the tableHeaderView. The height of this detailsView will vary slightly and is not known immediately in view did load. The detailsView also has it's own subViews that have their own auto layout constraints. All auto layout is being done programatically. Let me post some sample code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

      self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.detailsView;

      }

    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

      [self loadDetails];

    }

    -(void)loadDetails
    {
      //Omitted but does the following:
      //1. Makes a call to the api to get details 
      //2. Once received sets the details to the detailsView
      //3. Details could vary which influences detailView height size.
    }

    - (DetailsView *)detailsView
    {
      if(!_detailsView)
      {
        __weak DetailedViewController *_self = self;

        _detailsView = [DetailsView new];

        _detailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        _detailsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    }

    return _detailsView;

    }

-(void)updateViewConstraints
{

  NSDictionary *views = @{
                          @"table"      : self.tableView,
                          };

  //Comment Detail View
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[table]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];
  [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[table]-0-|" options:0 metrics:0 views:views]];


}
```

The problem with this approach is the tableHeaderView is pushed up to the top, meaning I can't scroll all the way through it properly. I'm not sure why this is happening. What I did as a test was replaced the detailsView with a UIImageView as follows.

```
-(UIImageView *)testImageView
{
    if(!_testImageView)
    {

        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"blackImage"] ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

        _testImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

        _testImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    }

    return _testImageView;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.testImageView;
}
```

This code produces exactly what I need without knowing the height or any of the dimensions of the image.

[image]
    As evidence by the photo, the header view is fully viewable and scrollable and I did not need to know any size of the image for this to work. I'd like to achieve the same thing with a UIView instead of the UIImageView for the tableHeaderView.

**Important Notes:**
The details view is not added as a sub view
The details view has not vertical height constraints or any constraints computed
The details view sub views have constraints computed programatically

**Things I've Researched:**
I've looked into instrinsicSize, sizeThatFits, anything that would allow a UIView to fill up the parent container view (tableHeaderView). I've tried various combinations of things with no success.

If anyone has a solution for how to solve this problem I'd appreciate it greatly!

(Let me know if this is not enough code to convey the context of the problem and I will post more.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize
```

0) Init your header generically, being sure that the constraints hit all four sides of the headerView's frame.

1) Set the frame of the header view using

```
systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize
```

2) Assign your header view to the tableview's frame

For example:

```
self.headerView = [[YourCustomHeaderView alloc] initWithYourCustomObject:obj];
self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, SCREEN_WIDTH, [self.headerView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height);
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;
```